# Unable to download file from S3 in NextJS, persistent error using pipe()

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js

In a NextJS 14 project, I have a server-side endpoint to download a pdf file from an S3 bucket:

**/api/download/route.ts**

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"
import { Readable } from "stream"

// Securely import AWS credentials from environment variables
const S3_REGION = process.env.AWS_S3_REGION
const S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID
const S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
const S3_BUCKET_NAME = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME

if (
  !S3_REGION ||
  !S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID ||
  !S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ||
  !S3_BUCKET_NAME
) {
  throw new Error("Missing AWS S3 credentials in environment variables!")
}

const s3Client = new S3Client({
  region: S3_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
})

export async function POST(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  const bodyString = await request.text()
  const data = JSON.parse(bodyString) // Parse the JSON data
  if (!data || !data.key) {
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
  }
  const { key } = data

  // Download the file from S3 using "key"
  try {
    const bucketParams = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: key,
    }
    // Get the object from S3
    const fileStream = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams))

    // Retrieve content type and filename
    const contentType = fileStream.Metadata?.["Content-Type"]
    const filename =
      fileStream.Metadata?.["Content-Disposition"]?.split("=")[1].trim() ?? key

    // Before setting the Content-Type header, ensure that contentType has a value
    if (contentType) {
      response.headers.set("Content-Type", contentType)
    } else {
      // Handle the case where the content type is missing
      console.error("Content type is missing in file metadata")
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        error: "Missing content type",
      })
    }

    // Set appropriate headers for download
    response.headers.set("Content-Type", contentType)
    response.headers.set(
      "Content-Disposition",
      `attachment; filename=${filename}`,
    )

    // Pipe the S3 object stream to the response
    if (fileStream.Body !== null) {
      if (fileStream.Body instanceof Readable) {
        await fileStream.Body.pipe(response.body)
      } else {
        // Handle non-readable stream type
      }
    } else {
      console.error("File stream body is null!")
      return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        error: "Missing file content",
      })
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ success: true, key })
  } catch (error) {
    // Explicitly cast the error to a string
    return NextResponse.json({ success: false, error: String(error) })
  }
}
```

This endpoint receives the filename as a variable called `key` and uses it to download the file from the S3 bucket.

The code seems fine but there’s a persistent error on the following line:

```
await fileStream.Body.pipe(response.body)
```

That says:

> Argument of type 'ReadableStream | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'WritableStream'.

I am already doing an explicit typecheck on `fileStream.Body`. What else am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried modifying the piping algorithm to this:

```
const writableStream = NextResponse.writableStream()
fileStream.Body.pipe(writableStream)
```

But this too fails saying:

> Property 'writableStream' does not exist on type 'NextResponse'.